# clicking a HTML href with enter key without javascript

Tags: html, keyboard-events, enter, buttonclick

hi i have a div wrapped in image tag as below:

```
<div id="SubmitButtonDIV" style="position: relative; left: 70px; top: 15px"><img
id="btnDOB" alt="" src="PsychOImages/calculate-white.jpg"
onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';" tabindex=4 /></div>
```

i want to use **keyboard controls** over it, i have set its **TabIndex** to **4** now when tab reaches this image contained in a **Div** i want to use **Enter button** for clicking it **instead** of a **mouse click**.

Is there a HTML property for doing it without using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just put an a href around the image and set the tabindex there?

Comment: i tried but no luck... there is a jquery function called at "btnDOB" image click .....

Comment: Exactly.  This is what *A*nchor tags are for.

Comment: i have turned into something like this '<a onclick="ValidatationCheck();" tabindex=4 >
                                                        <img id="loginbtn" alt="" src="PsychOImages/login-error_07.jpg" />
                                                    </a>' but still no help

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btnDOB').keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == '13')
    {
        //Do your thing
    }
});
```